# Replacing white or black by alpha channel in raster in QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2.8

[image]

I'd like to replace black or white in black and white raster in QGIS 2.8. I perceived that in some other raster where "nan" value automatically occurred and only white or black is being displayed.